# Rainfly window repair

Tags: camping

I have a Marmot Limelight tent that the see-through window needs reglued around the edge onto the tent. Is there a common household glue that can be used for this? And what is the best glue and/ or procedure for repairing this?

Comment: Literally the first link from when I google ["repair tent window"](https://craftandroam.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/marmot-tent-repairing-polyurethane-windows/) describes this exact problem and how to fix it.

Comment: I guess a tent would need an adhesive that remains flexible. You could try [Copydex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copydex) and one advantage is that it is not so strong that it can't be removed if unsuccessful. You won't be able to remove all of it from the fabric, where it has soaked in, but you will be able to peel it from the window. If the window has only partially separated, this would be good to work into the cracks.

Comment: The link from @bob1 has good information. But make sure your model of the tent has the same fabric and window material as the one in the link. (REI should be able to tell you that info if you no longer have the packaging or tag that says it. Or you can google your exact model to make sure.) Make sure you get a seam sealant compatible with both those materials. It should say on the seam sealant packaging (or in the product description if you buy online) which materials it's compatible with.

Comment: The link posted by @bob1 is even mentioning the _exact same type of tent_. It literally could apply more directly to OPs question.

Answer (score 3):

As the comments could be removed at some point I'll transform @Bob1's comment into an answer:

This page here essentially explains step-by-step how to solve your problem - they also talk about a Marmot Limelight tent, and also have the issue that one of the transparent 'windows' came loose.

--> [MARMOT TENT – REPAIRING POLYURETHANE WINDOWS](https://craftandroam.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/marmot-tent-repairing-polyurethane-windows/)

To summarize (in case the link gets broken in the future):

- Peel the window off completely.
- Peel off any glue remainders.
- Clean area of old glue residue with some cleaning alcohol (only the seam part, try not to get it on other areas of the tent).
- Apply new proper glue in the place where you cleaned off the old glue . The linked page recommends "Seam Grip" - maybe just ask your local outdoor store, they should be able to help you.
- Glue in the window and put some weights on it so it doesn't move during curing.
- Enjoy newly sealed window!